# Strikeout - Then Red Text - Then Normal text - In Select option (dropdown)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an HTML and CSS like the following image.
Is it possible using normal `<select></select>` with CSS option.

I tried with this but didn't work as expected like the image.

```css
  .text-style {color:blue;}
  .text-style1 {color:red;}
```

```html
<select>
     <option value="1" class="strikeout text-style"><s>stirke through text</s>RED TEXT - Normal Text</option>
    <option value="2" disabled="true">Some Text 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="strikeout text-style">S̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶T̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶3̶</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: NOt going to happen with a select element.

Comment: @epascarello what are the options?

Comment: Use something like Select2 or any of the other select box replacement scripts out there.